# HTTP Response Format incorrect?

Tags: c++, sockets, httpresponse

I was looking at creating WebServers with C++.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqEqjODUkWY) by Sloan Kelly, and referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102935/how-to-format-the-http-response) here.

I wrote (improperly adapted) the following code (showing the sending part only):

```cpp
std::stringstream make_response;
make_response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
make_response << "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n";
make_response << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
make_response << "Content-Length: 88\r\n";
make_response << "\r\n";
make_response << "Hello!";
std::string finished_response = make_response.str();

send(client, finished_response.c_str(), finished_response.length()+1, 0);
```

What is the problem here? When I connect to `127.0.0.1:8000`, the screen is entirely blank.

I know that the request reaches me, as I have printed it in the console:

```
C:\Users\Jaideep Shekhar\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\ProjectC++\Library\v0.1\main>webserver.exe
Listening for incoming connections...
Client connected!
Client says: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

@_M
Client disconnected.
```

You can copy the whole source code from [here](https://pastebin.com/zcypjMnb) and open up your terminal:

```
g++ webserver.cpp -o webserver.exe -lws2_32 && webserver.exe
```

Note that this code is for Windows OS.

*Edit*: Thanks to a comment, I solved the problem (see code below). Any improvements or problems in the code are welcome to be pointed out.

*Edit2*: How would I send images? I am opening the file opened with `std::ios::binary`, but it is not being recieved by the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, one of the headers in the shown HTTP response is completely wrong. HTTP 1.1 is a fairly complicated protocol. You must understand what every one of those headers does, instead of just blindly copying from some example somewhere. The formal specifications for HTTP is [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). You need to study it, in order to learn how to correctly assemble an HTTP message. P.S. On top of everything else, the `send()` call is also wrong, and will write an extra null byte (as part of the wrong response).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What is the minimum header requirement, besides `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n`? As for copying, recall our first Hello World programs. ;-)

Comment: Please see the formal specification for RFC 2616. HTTP is a complicated protocol. The absolute minimal HTTP response is a single blank line that separates the header from the body portion, and nothing else. But, it's not very useful, is it? So, you need spend some time reading and understanding the formal specifications.

Comment: Off the top, `Content-Length` header promises 88 bytes of content, but the server only sends 6. The client is probably sitting there waiting for the remaining 82.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Lol! Does this really hang the client? Woah, you are right!

Comment: There is no such thing as an HTML response, and there is no HTML here at all. Just a lot of malformed HTTP.

Comment: @user207421 Please do give ___constructive__ criticism_. Do you think your comment helps me (or anyone else) at all? In addition, the HTML in in another file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like the format and headers were all correct after all. I made a mistake in responding that I am sending 88 bytes of content, while I sent 5.

In fact, to avoid these issues, I have now put the HTML in its separate file.

The relevant part looks like this now:

```cpp
// Transfer the whole HTML to a std::string
std::fstream grab_content("home.html");
std::stringstream make_content;
make_content << grab_content.rdbuf();
std::string finished_content;
finished_content = make_content.str();

// Create the HTTP Response
std::stringstream make_response;
make_response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
make_response << "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n";
make_response << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
make_response << "Content-Length: " << finished_content.length() << "\r\n";
make_response << "\r\n";
make_response << finished_content;
// Transfer it to a std::string to send
std::string finished_response = make_response.str();

// Send the HTTP Response
send(client, finished_response.c_str(), finished_response.length(), 0);  // flag = 0
```